# Download pdf report not working in alfresco community

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

I'm using alfresco community 5.0.d and when I try to download a pdf report then I get "Failed to load PDF Document".

Also in console, there is no error.

[image]

Below is screenshot of download report option.

[image]

How could I fix this issue of pdf loading?
Also for time being I would like to remove this download option of pdf? how to achieve this too?

UPDATE:

catalina.out log shows a error as below.

```
2017-02-08 17:29:20,375  ERROR [report.client.AbstractBeCPGReportClient] [http-bio-8080-exec-8] Error accessing report server timeStamp is null
 2017-02-08 17:30:12,048  ERROR [report.client.AbstractBeCPGReportClient] [http-bio-8080-exec-1] Unable to parse response
 java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:601)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:631)
    at fr.becpg.report.client.AbstractBeCPGReportClient.getTemplateTimeStamp(AbstractBeCPGReportClient.java:85)
    at fr.becpg.repo.report.engine.impl.BeCPGReportServerClient.sendTplFile(BeCPGReportServerClient.java:136)
    at fr.becpg.repo.report.engine.impl.BeCPGReportServerClient.access$000(BeCPGReportServerClient.java:49)
    at fr.becpg.repo.report.engine.impl.BeCPGReportServerClient$1.doInReportSession(BeCPGReportServerClient.java:88)
    at fr.becpg.report.client.AbstractBeCPGReportClient.executeInSession(AbstractBeCPGReportClient.java:181)
    at fr.becpg.repo.report.engine.impl.BeCPGReportServerClient.createReport(BeCPGReportServerClient.java:79)
    at fr.becpg.repo.report.search.impl.ReportServerSearchRenderer.renderReport(ReportServerSearchRenderer.java:128)
    at fr.becpg.repo.report.search.impl.ExportSearchServiceImpl.createReport(ExportSearchServiceImpl.java:42)
    at fr.becpg.repo.web.scripts.report.ExportSearchWebScript.execute(ExportSearchWebScript.java:97)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer$3.execute(RepositoryContainer.java:482)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:457)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecute(RepositoryContainer.java:551)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecuteAs(RepositoryContainer.java:619)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.executeScriptInternal(RepositoryContainer.java:399)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.executeScript(RepositoryContainer.java:280)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:378)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:209)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.servlet.WebScriptServlet.service(WebScriptServlet.java:132)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.alfresco.web.app.servlet.GlobalLocalizationFilter.doFilter(GlobalLocalizationFilter.java:61)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2017-02-08 17:30:12,048  ERROR [report.client.AbstractBeCPGReportClient] [http-bio-8080-exec-1] Error accessing report server timeStamp is null
```

UPDATE:

**Console error**
[image: console error]

Thanks.

Comment: Anything in your server side log?

Comment: @Lista I have updated the post with catalina.out error log.

Comment: It looks like you have download a broken / incorrectly configured third-party add-in for Alfresco (notice the non-Alfresco package name in your stacktrace). Why did you do so, and do you need it? Try removing it if not

Comment: BeCPGReportServerClient is used for create the report(pdf format) so user can download it.

Answer (score 0):

@nikhil84, I suggest using this code to generate the pdf rendition so you can get rid of the library causing the error.

1. Use the [Alfresco SDK](http://docs.alfresco.com/community/concepts/alfresco-sdk-intro.html) to create an alfresco [all-in-one project](http://docs.alfresco.com/community/concepts/alfresco-sdk-archetypes-aio.html).
2. Add the PDFRenditionService to repoAmp/src/main/java/com/yourCompany/alfresco/service

   public static final String PDFRENDITIONNAME = "pdfRendition";
   public static final QName pdfRenditionQName = QName.createQName(NamespaceService.CONTENT_MODEL_1_0_URI, PDFRENDITIONNAME);
   RenditionDefinition pdfRenditionDefinition = renditionService.createRenditionDefinition(pdfRenditionQName, ReformatRenderingEngine.NAME);
   pdfRenditionDefinition.setParameterValue(AbstractRenderingEngine.PARAM_MIME_TYPE, MimetypeMap.MIMETYPE_PDF);
   renditionService.saveRenditionDefinition(pdfRenditionDefinition);

   // Execute this line in its own transaction
   renditionService.render(sourceNodeRef, pdfRenditionDefinition);

   ChildAssociationRef renditionAssoc = renditionService.getRenditionByName(sourceNodeRef, pdfRenditionName);
   if (renditionAssoc == null) return null
   return renditionAssoc.getChildRef()
3. Add an alfresco webscript into the repo amp that will call the PDFRenditionService
4. Determine how you want to trigger the webscript.
5. Examine the [alfresco-sdk-samples](https://github.com/Alfresco/alfresco-sdk-samples) for more information.

Comment: I'm using library as it render's and lets me download the pdf. It's kinda feature this library provides along with other feature. Also I do not know where exactly to put down this code for rendition and let user download the pdf file. If you could let me know the steps and files to modify for this. Thanks!

Comment: You can put this code in a PDFRenditionService which can be called by a custom webscript.  Also, the renditionService is of type org.alfresco.service.cmr.rendition.RenditionService

Comment: Ok that sounds good but I'm new to alfresco dev and do not have much idea about the creating custom webscript. If you could joint down steps or a blog then that would be great. Also would this pdf rendition allow the download of pdf ?